# Script calling another script, stdout/stderr redirection

Tags: unix, io-redirection

**Problem**

```
Have a multi_exec.pl that shall handle timed-out execution of command provided.
And we call this multi_exec.pl at various places in our legacy applciation.

Sample call :
$grab = `multi_exec.pl -1 'bcp_cmd-1' 'bcp_cmd-2' ... 'bcp_cmd-n'`
```

want to understand how to achieve the below using STDOUT[ERR] re-directions

1. capture bcp STDOUT[ERR] of individual BCP commands on the terminal
2. while need to capture failure messages on STDERR from multi_exec.pl
3. STDOUT of multi_exec.pl needs to go to /dev/null ( don't want to capture STDOUT
   )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- while need to capture failure messages on STDERR from multi_exec.pl

Nothing special needs to be done for this - STDERR of the parent script as well as the individual commands will go to the terminal by default

- STDOUT of multi_exec.pl needs to go to /dev/null (don't want to capture STDOUT)
- capture bcp STDOUT[ERR] of individual BCP commands on the terminal

These are conflicting requirements because STDOUT of the parent script as well as the individual bcp commands will end up on the terminal by default.  There is no way to bifurcate just one of them to be sent to /dev/null.  You could modify `multi_exec.pl` so that it writes its own output to a file, if specified.  If no file is specified, it shouldn't write anything to stdout at all.  So, it is ensured the STDOUT of `multi_exec.pl` is always from bcp commands.

Comment: Thanks , changed `multi_exec.pl` to conditionally supress STDOUT. do we really don't have any way to independently control STDOUT of both the scripts ? using I/O re-directs ?